# Filterable portfolio with title overlay

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a filterable portfolio with a coloured overlay that shows the title of the project such as this:

Overlay example:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_image_overlay_fade

However when I try to apply this to my portfolio code, the filter doesn't work.

Portfolio code: https://codepen.io/ford1234/pen/xLPELL

```
<div class="toolbar mb2 mt2">
<button class="pbtn fil-cat" href="" data-rel="all">All</button>
<button class="pbtn fil-cat" data-rel="live">Live</button>
<button class="pbtn fil-cat" data-rel="projects">Projects</button>
<button class="pbtn fil-cat" data-rel="events">Events</button>
</div> 

<div style="clear:both;"></div> 
<div id="portfolio">
<div class="tile scale-anm live all">
<img src="https://dev.dcrc.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/autonomy-and-
automation.jpg" alt="">
</div>
<div class="tile scale-anm projects all">
<a href="#"><img src="http://dev.dcrc.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/diy-
citizenship-crop.jpg" alt="" /></a>
</div>
<div class="tile scale-anm events all">
<a href="#"><img src="http://dev.dcrc.org.uk/wp-
content/uploads/2017/08/pervasive-media-cookbook-2.jpg" alt="" /></a>
 </div>
 <div class="tile scale-anm live all">
 <a href="#"><img src="http://dev.dcrc.org.uk/wp-
content/uploads/2017/08/amb-lit.jpg" alt="" /></a>
 </div>




</div>

<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Thanks in advance, I've got into a muddle!

Comment: What isn't working? The codepen link looks fine to me. You need to be more clear what you want to happen... and what's happening that isn't favorable.

Comment: Sorry, it's that when I click onto 'Live' for example, it doesn't filter the projects like here: https://codepen.io/creotip/pen/dfjeF (should have included that link before)

Comment: All thats wrong is that you haven't included jquery (or its not included properly). Include jquery and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have jQuery included (or it has not been included correctly). It works exactly are required once jQuery is included.

In CodePen, you can go to the Javascript settings in CodePen and select jQuery from the Quick-add dropdown, but you will need to check why its not working in your local file. Make sure that it's included correctly and that the version is compatible with you code. The following is the version that works in your CodePen:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
```